# Can Thymeleaf do localized template lookups like Freemarker?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker, thymeleaf

Freemarker (by default) [uses the locale to build the file names it looks for](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html#ref_directive_include_localized) when loading and including templates. For example, loading `tos.ftl` (the template) with the `en_US` locale would look for:

1. tos_en_US.ftl
2. tos_en.ftl
3. tos.ftl

This can be useful to translate whole pages when the pages are completely different between different languages. For example, a "Terms of Service" page might be mostly static so different languages would have completely different content. In this case, it is a hassle to externalize the whole content to messages loaded from message bundles.

I am now learning Thymeleaf and can't find any information about a similar functionality. I know that Thymeleaf uses [localized message bundles](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text) to fill in `th:text` elements, but can it load localized versions of the **template files**?

Note: I'm using Spring Boot

Comment: I opened a feature request for this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/497

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit too late but here is how I would attempt to solve this using the current version of Thymeleaf:

Presuming you have these 2 localised templates under path (from the template root) `path/to/template`:

```
localized_template_en.html
localized_template_ru.html
```

In your `SomeController.class`:

```
@GetMapping( "/locale_test" )
public String getLocalisedPage( Model model ) {
    return "path/to/template/localized_template_" 
             + LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
}
```

As a result you will get the correct template given you use Spring localisation features (such as `LocaleChangeInterceptor`). If not - instead of using `LocaleContextHolder` implement your custom logic for postfix selection.

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf's behaviour the same as [Spring 4 MVC Internationalization](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-annotation-example) (I guess you using Thymeleaf with Spring??), it uses `messages.properties` to realize that.
For example you have a template with `#{hello}` message:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <span th:text="#{hello}">
</body>
```

`#{hello}` text will be binded to the `messages.properties` proprty `hello`.

If you `locale` would be another, e.g. `ru_RU` you just add `messages_ru_RU.properties` and change the `locale` of your application.

After that, your message will be taken from localized properties file.
**Note that necessarily** to have `messages.properties` file if you using localized messages file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it misses my intended meaning. I know about message bundles, but I was wondering about the actual template file itself having localized versions. I'll clarify the question.